# input date in jsp using nestedPath

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp

I am facing currently a huge issue : I can not retrieve date input by user in JSP page.

JSP code :

```
<form:form method="POST" action="myAction"> 
<tr><td>Date</td>
<td>
<spring:nestedPath path="myClasse.startDate" >
<input type="text" name="startDate" value="<c:out value="${status.value}"/> "/></spring:nestedPath>
</td></tr>
```

I input date in all existing forms. my code part corresponding to the retrieval of startDate in the Controller:

```
System.out.println("date: " + myClasse.getStartDate());
```

give me null

Here are some details that can help :

I have this in my model class :

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "start_date", length = 19)
public Date getStartDate()
{
    return this.startDate;
}

public void setStartDate(Date startDate)
{
    this.startDate = startDate;
}
```

Service class :

```
session.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT name where startDate=:startDate").setParameter("startDate", "startDate");
```

Comment: I think you need to use PropertyEditor to NPCI convert string value entered in form to java.util.Date

Comment: Should you do it in JSP or in the controller ?

Comment: It is a config on server, you will have to register it with Spring, there is bunch of config related to it.  Look it up in Spring documentation

Comment: do you have an example of how to implement it ?

Comment: Okay things have a changed a bit over time, PropertyEditor was what I used few years back.  You can look at this example for latest way of doing this:  http://linkedjava.blogspot.in/2011/06/spring-controller-with-date-object.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that can fix this problem :

In my controller class I added this :

```
 @InitBinder
 public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder)
 {
  SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  dateFormat.setLenient(false);
  binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
 }
```

Hope that will help people facing this issue :)